# Is there is any module which creates new users by reading a spreadsheet/excel file?

Tags: users

Could anyone tell me if there is any module which creates new users by reading a spreadsheet/excel file? I have added few more fields to the user registration form, and that might make this a bit tricky! Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: dont understand how come someone would downvote a simple question!

Comment: I guess you could pretty well Google up User Import module on your own. Most of simple questions already have answers easy to find, so asking them is - usually - a sign of lack of effort and "do my work for me" approach. Not always, but when it may look like that, be prepared to get downvotes, or show what you have tried and how did it failed your expectation. But then it's not a simple question anymore.

Comment: agreed totally! My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the [user import module](https://drupal.org/project/user_import)

> Import users into Drupal, or update existing users, with data from a
>   CSV file (comma separated file). Provides a wide range of features out
>   of the box, and a comprehensive API to customise imports.

Comment: well..I have seen this module but it supports only CSV, but my client wants excel import.

Comment: Then save the excel file as a csv file

Comment: Full excel support is way above anything inside Drupal will be ever able to do, unless someone'll pour nice amount of money to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my experience, importing users could be a tricky task.
The user import module is nice and easy, but if you'll need more features, you'll end frustrated. Some field types aren't supported (e.g. date fields). Importing Profile2 fields, if you'll need them, is almost impossible. The last patch is one year old (it's mine), it's not 100% working, and no other tried to continue working on it. But if you can switch to CSV, it'll get you up and running very quickly. You can send an email to the new users so they can activate their account, you can automatically generate usernames and roles etc.

If XLS is mandatory you should switch to [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xls) and the [Feeds XLS](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xls) parser. By adding [Feeds Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_profile2) you can also easily import Profile2 fields. Just remember that if you use Feeds, you won't be able to automatically enable and mail users. You'll have to modify Drupal's registration mail template to suit you needs, and then manually enable the imported users. At that point they'll receive the signup email.

Since I've started my site using User Import I'm continuing with it, but after importing basic user info I'm passing the CSV again to the Feeds module in order to update the users with the Profile2 info and with the fields that aren't supported by User Import. I'm also considering to totally switch to the Feeds module, but at the moment I don't have time, plus I'm too lazy.

So: if you want an easy module, CSV is OK and you have simple fields to import, go for User Import. If you need XLS, you have advanced fields or Profile2 info and you don't mind having some extra complexity, Feeds is the way.